# Merge two pandas data frames, one has infrequent dates and should be merged by the most recent date

Tags: python, pandas, merge

`a`, `b` are pandas data frames, and `a` updates less frequently than `b`.
E.g.

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'id': np.array([1, 3, 4, 9]*2),
                  'date': np.repeat(['2021-01-03', '2021-02-06'], 4),
                  'score': np.linspace(0, 1, 8)})
a['date'] = pd.to_datetime(a['date'])

b = pd.DataFrame({'id': np.array([1, 3, 4, 9]*5),
                  'date': np.repeat(['2021-01-03', '2021-01-15', '2021-01-23', '2021-02-08', '2021-02-17'], 4),
                  'value': np.linspace(0, 1, 20)})
b['date'] = pd.to_datetime(b['date'])
```

I want to merge the two frames, by matching the ids and the date in `b` with the most recent date in `a`, so in this example I want the following pairings of the dates for the merge:

```
b          -> a
2021-01-03 -> 2021-01-03
2021-01-15 -> 2021-01-03
2021-01-23 -> 2021-01-03
2021-02-08 -> 2021-02-06
2021-02-17 -> 2021-02-06
```

I can do this with a for-loop over each of the dates in `a`, selecting the data in `b` that lies between each pair of adjacent dates in `a`, adding the `score` from `a` as a new column, and then concatenating these frames together, but is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: Have you checked `merge_asof()` ?

Comment: @CeliusStingher I had not heard of that function but I will definitely be using it from now on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) by `on` and `by` parameters:

```
df = pd.merge_asof(b, a, on='date', by='id')
```

For test was renamed column to `date1`:

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'id': np.array([1, 3, 4, 9]*2),
                  'date': np.repeat(['2021-01-03', '2021-02-06'], 4),
                  'score': np.linspace(0, 1, 8)})
a['date'] = pd.to_datetime(a['date'])

b = pd.DataFrame({'id': np.array([1, 3, 4, 9]*5),
                  'date1': np.repeat(['2021-01-03', '2021-01-15', '2021-01-23', '2021-02-08', '2021-02-17'], 4),
                  'value': np.linspace(0, 1, 20)})
b['date1'] = pd.to_datetime(b['date1'])
```

---

```
df = pd.merge_asof(b, a, left_on='date1', right_on='date', by='id')
print (df)
    id      date1     value       date     score
0    1 2021-01-03  0.000000 2021-01-03  0.000000
1    3 2021-01-03  0.052632 2021-01-03  0.142857
2    4 2021-01-03  0.105263 2021-01-03  0.285714
3    9 2021-01-03  0.157895 2021-01-03  0.428571
4    1 2021-01-15  0.210526 2021-01-03  0.000000
5    3 2021-01-15  0.263158 2021-01-03  0.142857
6    4 2021-01-15  0.315789 2021-01-03  0.285714
7    9 2021-01-15  0.368421 2021-01-03  0.428571
8    1 2021-01-23  0.421053 2021-01-03  0.000000
9    3 2021-01-23  0.473684 2021-01-03  0.142857
10   4 2021-01-23  0.526316 2021-01-03  0.285714
11   9 2021-01-23  0.578947 2021-01-03  0.428571
12   1 2021-02-08  0.631579 2021-02-06  0.571429
13   3 2021-02-08  0.684211 2021-02-06  0.714286
14   4 2021-02-08  0.736842 2021-02-06  0.857143
15   9 2021-02-08  0.789474 2021-02-06  1.000000
16   1 2021-02-17  0.842105 2021-02-06  0.571429
17   3 2021-02-17  0.894737 2021-02-06  0.714286
18   4 2021-02-17  0.947368 2021-02-06  0.857143
19   9 2021-02-17  1.000000 2021-02-06  1.000000
```

Comment: @Alex - I add test solution for possible see correct mapping between dates. Maybe somebody miss it...